# unable to convert negative values to positive in array?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, loops, absolute-value

I need to return `true`/`false` if there was any integer converted to positive in an array, I am able to return true or false however I am not able to convert the negative integers into positive?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int convertArray (int a[],int sizeofArray )     

{
bool v = false;
for (int i=0; i<sizeofArray; i++)
{   

    if(a[i]<0)
    {
        abs(a[i]);
        v = true;

    }

  cout << i << "  " << a[i] << endl;  
}
return v;



}
int main()

{
    int b[5] = {1,-2,3,5,2};
    cout << convertArray (b,5)<<endl;

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with java?

Comment: Have you looked at a suitable reference documentation of [`abs`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs), in particular whether its argument is passed by value or reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement:

```
abs(a[i]);
```

does just the conversion but the value is lost since you are not re-assigning to the corresponding array element and the parameter is not passed by reference. You should have:

```
a[i] = abs(a[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your line

```
abs(a[i]);
```

calculates the absolute value of the array "a" at the position i and discards it because it will remain inacessible.

You have to write

```
a[i] = abs(a[i]);
```

or more simply

```
a[i] = -a[i];
```

to trasform the negative number a[i] into positive.

Answer (score 1):

`abs` just returns the absolute value of its argument, which you then ignore by not using it. Instead, you should reassign this value back to the element of the array:

```
a[i] = abs(a[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only getting the absolute value, not setting it, 
you would need to do `a[i] = abs(a[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

Just Convert while retrieving data from an array, This will help you!

`arr[i]= Math.abs(arr[i]);`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Good answer, but not for a question tagged `C++`  :-)